# Agrupar por tiempo, en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un pequeño conflicto al agrupar algunos datos usando Pandas. El ejercicio lo he resuelto usando un `for` y algunos condicionales (no soy programadora), pero me parece que se puede resolver más fácil y elegante usando pandas.

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente estructura:

```
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
2021-04-28 22:55:00  1.21312   1.21300
2021-04-28 22:56:00  1.21307   1.21317
2021-04-28 22:57:00  1.21312   1.21314
2021-04-28 22:58:00  1.21319   1.21320
2021-04-28 22:59:00  1.21300   1.21310
...                      ...       ...
2021-04-29 00:51:00  1.21393   1.21390
2021-04-29 00:52:00  1.21391   1.21386
2021-04-29 00:53:00  1.21370   1.21386
2021-04-29 00:54:00  1.21386   1.21391
2021-04-29 00:55:00  1.21391   1.21386
```

El index es un `DataTime  (*2021-04-29 00:55:00*) '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Necesito hacer grupos de datos cada cinco (5) minutos, y realizar algunos promedios con los valores (*Val_ini* y *Val_fin*). Debería quedar algo así:

```
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
2021-04-28 22:55:00  1.21312   1.21300
2021-04-28 22:56:00  1.21307   1.21317
2021-04-28 22:57:00  1.21312   1.21314
2021-04-28 22:58:00  1.21319   1.21320
2021-04-28 22:59:00  1.21300   1.21310
                     Promedio  Promedio
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
                     en 5min   en 5min

2021-04-28 13:00:00  1.13120   1.23000
2021-04-28 13:01:00  1.13070   1.23170
2021-04-28 13:02:00  1.13120   1.23140
2021-04-28 13:03:00  1.13190   1.23200
2021-04-28 13:04:00  1.13000   1.13100
                     Promedio  Promedio
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
                     en 5min   en 5min

2021-04-28 13:05:00  1.36162   1.33000
2021-04-28 13:06:00  1.37047   1.35127
2021-04-28 13:07:00  1.38712   1.38140
2021-04-28 13:08:00  1.32419   1.32204
2021-04-28 13:09:00  1.30000   1.30105
                     Promedio  Promedio
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
                     en 5min   en 5min
```

Mi DataFrame se llama ***rango_datos***

Intente agrupar los datos así:

```
  agruparcion = rango_datos.index.to_period("5min")

  print(rango_datos.groupby([ agrupacion, rango_datos.index.time]).sum())
```

Pero no veo que se formen los grupos que necesito.

¿Me podríais hacer favor de orientarme, en este aspecto?

Comment: Fe de erratas: (en la variable  agruparcion, se quizo escribir  agrupacion)

  agrupacion = rango_datos.index.to_period("5min")

  print(rango_datos.groupby([ agrupacion, rango_datos.index.time]).sum())

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para corregirla.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo del todo la funcionalidad de `.to_period()`, que nunca había usado, pero por las pruebas que he realizado da la sensación de que no puedes usarlo para agrupar de 5 en 5 minutos, sino tan solo por minutos, o por horas, o por días, etc... pero no por fracción o múltiplo de esas unidades.

Creo que una solución mejor a lo que buscas es utilizar `.resample()`, si bien tiene un efecto secundario (¿indeseado?) de que entre la hora inicial y la final aparecerán *todos* los intervalos de 5 minutos, aún si el dataframe original no contenía datos en esos intervalos.

Veámoslo con un ejemplo:

He copiado los datos de tu dataframe, omitiendo la zona en que aparecían "...", por lo que mi dataframe tiene solo datos para los primeros cinco minutos y los cinco últimos de tu intervalo:

```
>>> df
                     Val_ini  Val_fin
hora                                 
2021-04-28 22:55:00  1.21312  1.21300
2021-04-28 22:56:00  1.21307  1.21317
2021-04-28 22:57:00  1.21312  1.21314
2021-04-28 22:58:00  1.21319  1.21320
2021-04-28 22:59:00  1.21300  1.21310
2021-04-29 00:51:00  1.21393  1.21390
2021-04-29 00:52:00  1.21391  1.21386
2021-04-29 00:53:00  1.21370  1.21386
2021-04-29 00:54:00  1.21386  1.21391
2021-04-29 00:55:00  1.21391  1.21386
```

Utilizo `.resample()` con un periodo de 5min, y calculo lel promedio de cada intervalo:

```
>>> df.resample("5min").mean()
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
hora                                  
2021-04-28 22:55:00  1.21310  1.213122
2021-04-28 23:00:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:05:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:10:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:15:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:20:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:25:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:30:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:35:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:40:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:45:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:50:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-28 23:55:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:00:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:05:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:10:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:15:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:20:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:25:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:30:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:35:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:40:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:45:00      NaN       NaN
2021-04-29 00:50:00  1.21385  1.213882
2021-04-29 00:55:00  1.21391  1.213860
```

Ahi ves a qué me refería con lo de incluir todos los intervalos.

Si no te interesa tener los vacíos, siempre puedes usar `dropna()`

```
>>> df.resample("5min").mean().dropna()
                     Val_ini   Val_fin
hora                                  
2021-04-28 22:55:00  1.21310  1.213122
2021-04-29 00:50:00  1.21385  1.213882
2021-04-29 00:55:00  1.21391  1.213860
```

### Ampliación

Lo de `.dropna()` funciona si la métrica que estás calculando es la media (`.mean()`), pero no funcionaría por ejemplo para la suma, porque en ese caso el resultado estaría relleno con `0` en vez de con `NaN`

Una solución a ese problema podría ser implementar la función de agregación de modo que haga solo la suma si el grupo no está vacío. Así:

```
def agg(x, f):
    if not x.empty:
        return getattr(x,f)()

df.resample("5min").apply(lambda x: agg(x, "sum")).dropna()
```

---

```
                     Val_ini  Val_fin
hora                                 
2021-04-28 22:55:00  6.06550  6.06561
2021-04-29 00:50:00  4.85540  4.85553
2021-04-29 00:55:00  1.21391  1.21386
```

En vez de "sum" puedes poner "mean", "prod", "count", "max", "min", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Para dividir tu índice en intervalos de cinco minutos podrías utilizar

```
DataFrame.resample('5min')
```

si además quieres el valor de la media cada cinco minutos podrías agregar .mean() esto es

```
DataFrame.resample('5min').mean()
```

el resultado será la media de cada intervalo de 5 minutos de val_ini y val_fin.