# Seleccionar un dato cada cierto rango con pandas. [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

Un cordial saludo a todos. Estoy trabajando en Python y tengo un DataFrame del siguiente estilo. Esta indexado por fecha y hora.

```
                     Promed
2021-04-29 10:48:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 10:49:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:50:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:51:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 10:52:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:53:00  -0.4
2021-04-29 10:54:00   0.6
2021-04-29 10:55:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 10:56:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:57:00   0.4
2021-04-29 10:58:00   0.6
2021-04-29 10:59:00   0.2
2021-04-29 11:00:00   0.0
2021-04-29 11:01:00   0.2
2021-04-29 11:02:00   0.0
2021-04-29 11:03:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 11:04:00   1.0
2021-04-29 11:05:00   0.6
2021-04-29 11:06:00  -0.4
2021-04-29 11:07:00   0.6
2021-04-29 11:08:00  -0.6
2021-04-29 11:09:00   0.2
2021-04-29 11:10:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 11:11:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 11:12:00  -1.0

 Tiempo de ejecución: 2.046 seg
```

Seria posible, (usando pandas) seleccionar solamente los datos cada 5 minutos, por ejemplo los terminados 00, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55.Necesito indicarle que comience en un minuto especifico y que de  saltos cada x minutos por poner un ejemplo.

```
                      Promed
 2021-04-29 10:48:00  -0.2
 2021-04-29 10:49:00   0.2
[2021-04-29 10:50:00   0.2]
 2021-04-29 10:51:00  -0.2
 2021-04-29 10:52:00   0.2
 2021-04-29 10:53:00  -0.4
 2021-04-29 10:54:00   0.6
[2021-04-29 10:55:00  -0.2]
 2021-04-29 10:56:00   0.2
 2021-04-29 10:57:00   0.4
 2021-04-29 10:58:00   0.6
 2021-04-29 10:59:00   0.2
[2021-04-29 11:00:00   0.0]
 2021-04-29 11:01:00   0.2
 2021-04-29 11:02:00   0.0
 2021-04-29 11:03:00  -0.2
 2021-04-29 11:04:00   1.0
[2021-04-29 11:05:00   0.6]
 2021-04-29 11:06:00  -0.4
 2021-04-29 11:07:00   0.6
 2021-04-29 11:08:00  -0.6
 2021-04-29 11:09:00   0.2
[2021-04-29 11:10:00  -0.2]
 2021-04-29 11:11:00  -0.2
 2021-04-29 11:12:00  -1.0

 Tiempo de ejecución: 2.046 seg
```

Resultado esperado

```
                      Promed
2021-04-29 10:50:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:55:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 11:00:00   0.0
2021-04-29 11:05:00   0.6
2021-04-29 11:10:00  -0.2

 Tiempo de ejecución: 2.046 seg
```

Gracias.

Comment: Pregunta ¿en qué difiere esta pregunta con [la anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/448054/156327) (con otro usuario del mismo nombre)?

Comment: En la anterior selecciono grupos con cinco datos, en cada grupo. Aqui necesito seleccionar, UN SOLO DATO cada cierto tiempo. Lamento no saber tanto sobre pandas. la verdad es que no se como preguntar esto en google y no soy programadora, por eso recurro a ustedes. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que tu índice es ya de tipo `datetime()` pienso que la opción más simple es utilizar `df.resample()`. A esta función le puedes pasar como parámetro el tiempo del intervalo a resamplear, en tu caso `"5min"`. Lo que hace entonces la función es crear una especie de "sub-dataframes" que contienen todos los datos comprendidos en intervalos de 5 minutos.

Sobre tu ejemplo el primer intervalo iría de las 10:45:00 a las 10:49:59, el siguiente empezaría a las 10:50:00 e iría hasta 10:54:59, etc. En el caso de tu ejemplo el primer intervalo estaría "incompleto" pues tus datos no comienzan a las 10:45:00.

A cada uno de esos sub-dataframes, se les aplica seguidamente una función para resumir todos sus datos en uno solo. Esta función puede ser por ejemplo `.sum()` (te daría la suma de todos los datos dentro de esos 5 minutos), o bien `.mean()` (te daría el promedio), etc.

En tu caso particular creo que necesitas la función `.first()` que te devuelve simplemente el primer dato dentro del intervalo, y por tanto el que corresponde a un numero "redondo" de minutos múltiplo de 5.

Probémoslo:

```
>>> df.resample("5min").first()
                     Promed                       
2021-04-29 10:45:00    -0.2
2021-04-29 10:50:00     0.2
2021-04-29 10:55:00    -0.2
2021-04-29 11:00:00     0.0
2021-04-29 11:05:00     0.6
2021-04-29 11:10:00    -0.2
```

En efecto esto produce lo que buscabas, salvo quizás el primer dato, que etiqueta como 10:45:00 pero en realidad corresponde a las 10:48 debido a que el primer intervalo de 5 minutos estaba incompleto). Puedes evitar este problema eliminando las primeras filas de tu dataframe para que comience ya a las 10:50:00.

Answer (score 1):

***Muchísimas gracias a todos. Sus soluciones son muy bien recibidas y funcionan de manera impecable. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de escribir código para una persona desconocida y tener la amabilidad de explicarlo y compartirlo. Sois muy amables.***

También seria posible...

Seleccionar la fecha y hora de inicio, sugiriendo la cantidad de datos a generar en la variable "periodos" y el rango del tiempo en "frecuencia" (*usando* ***pandas.date_range()***)

```
# Se generara un index iniciando en "2021-04-29 10:50:00"
# Dicho index, contendra tres (3) fechas; periods=3
# Cada una con cinco (5) minutos de diferencia; freq="5min"
dti = pd.date_range("2021-04-29 10:50:00", periods=3, freq="5min")

>>> DatetimeIndex(['2021-04-29 10:50:00', '2021-04-29 10:55:00', '2021-04-29 11:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5T')


type(dti)

>>> <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>


# rango_datos es el DataFrame con toda la información
# Se localizara en el index de rango_datos, solamente las fechas contenidas en dti
rango_datos.loc[dti, :]

>>> 
                      Promed
2021-04-29 10:50:00   0.2
2021-04-29 10:55:00  -0.2
2021-04-29 11:00:00   0.0
```

En este ejemplo use periods=3, freq="5min", para poder ver las diferencias entre la cantidad de datos y la frecuencia de los mismos *(para que o queden cincos por todos lados y no saber cual es cual)*.

Todo se podria resumir a:

```
fecha_inicio = dt.datetime(2021,4,29,10,50,0)
dti = pd.date_range(fecha_inicio, periods=3, freq="5min")
rango_datos.loc[dti, :]
```

Comment: Comprendo gracias por la aclaración. Un GRACIAS nunca sobra ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo he hecho de la siguiente forma, espero que te sirva.

Tenemos el siguiente DataFrame con datos aleatorios similares a los tuyos:

```
       fecha      hora  promed
0 2021-04-29  10:48:00    -0.2
1 2021-04-29  10:49:00     0.2
2 2021-04-29  10:50:00    -0.4
3 2021-04-29  10:51:00    -0.5
4 2021-04-29  10:52:00    -0.1
5 2021-04-29  10:53:00    -0.4
6 2021-04-29  10:54:00    -0.3
7 2021-04-29  10:55:00    -0.2
8 2021-04-29  10:56:00    -0.2
9 2021-04-29  10:57:00    -0.2
```

Entonces, con el siguiente código iteramos el DataFrame indicando dos parámetros: una hora de inicio *start* y los saltos en minutos *x*:

```
x = 5
start = datetime.strptime("10:48:00", "%H:%M:%S")

dicc = {
    "fecha": [],
    "hora": [],
    "promed": []
}

for row in df.iloc:
    hora_formateada = datetime.strptime(row[1], "%H:%M:%S")

    if hora_formateada.minute % x == 0 and hora_formateada >= start:
        dicc["fecha"].append(row[0])
        dicc["hora"].append(row[1])
        dicc["promed"].append(row[2])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dicc)
```

La fila del DataFrame se añadirá a un nuevo DataFrame *df1* si la hora es superior a la dada y si se han dado los saltos de minutos correspondientes. En este caso, el salto se da cada 5 minutos, lo que daría la siguiente salida al imprimir el nuevo DataFrame:

```
       fecha      hora  promed
0 2021-04-29  10:50:00    -0.4
1 2021-04-29  10:55:00    -0.2
```